# Why does the search in Experience Profile return non-matches?

Tags: solr, experience-profile

I am trying a search in Experience Profile in Sitecore 8.1-3 with Solr 4.10 as the search provider.  I am noticing that sometimes it returns results that don't seem to match the search query at all.  For example - if I search for John Doe in the search bar, here is the query that I see in the search log file:

`?q=(type_t:(contact) AND (contact.fullname_t:(John Doe~0.5) OR contact.emails_sm:(John Doe~0.5)))&start=0&rows=100&fl=*,score&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_analytics_index)`

And when I run that query manually through the Solr interface I get back results that don't seem to match at all.  I'm not sure what the ~0.5 part of the query is.  Is that some sort of fuzzy match or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fuzzy query where `0.5` is similarity index

The similarity measurement is based on the `Damerau-Levenshtein` (optimal string alignment) algorithm. Sometimes you may get unexpected results in that case.

**In your case**, I believe that you are getting unexpected results because ~0.5 similarity applies to both terms `John` and `Doe`.

Comment: Interesting.  So I am wondering exactly how the search code works for the Experience Profile search.  It seems to me like maybe it first tries a regular search with the given text, then if it return zero results it retries the search using the fuzzy query.  Is that right?

Comment: @CoreyBurnett I think you should check the Search.log for that. 
if you see two consecutive queries, i.e. one is not fuzzy, and the following one is fuzzy, then it proves your theory. Otherwise, it's just trying to make a fuzzy search regardless of results from concrete query